# Solving simultaneous equations involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

This is a question from the book Discrete Mathematical Structures by Bernard Kolman, Robert C. Busby and Sharon Cutler Ross.

I want to find the explicit formula of the recurrence relation $g_n = 2g_{n-1} - 2g_{n-2}$ with initial conditions $g_1 = 1$ and $g_2 = 4$.

I form the characteristic equation $x^2 = 2x - 2$. I get $1+i$ and $1-i$ as roots.

Since there are 2 distinct roots, $g_n = us_1^n + vs_2^n$.

1. $g_1 = u(1+i)^1 + v(1-i)^1$
2. $g_2 = u(1+i)^2 + v(1-i)^2$

Simplyfing:

1. $(1+i)u + (1-i)v = 1$
2. $(2i)u + (-2i)v = 4$

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why not like any 'ol system of equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing your second equation by $2i$ and rearrange you get $$u-v=-2i$$
Inserting the expression for $u$ into the first and simplifying (try it!) you get 
$$2v-2i+1=0 \leftrightarrow v=i-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Because $\frac{2}{i}=\frac{i}{i}\frac{2}{i}=\frac{2i}{i^2}=-2i$

Comment: @Saiyan Please let me know if it doesn't make sense yet, and I will elaborate further.

Comment: I understood it. I got $g_n = \frac{-2i-1}{2}(i+1)^n + \frac{2-i}{2}(i-1)^n$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Saiyan I'm not familiar with the notation - what are $s_1^n$ and $s_2^n$?

Comment: They are the roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: @Saiyan Sorry, can't help you with that.